# struct member size and exc_bad_access error

Tags: c, struct, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to read a struct member in the following code. However, I'm either getting a exc_bad_access on the printf statement in the loop, or where the strcat copies the buffer. Not sure why, I believe I have the correct size for the struct. Is the problem likely to be with the terminator char?

Is there an easier way to do this? Seems very difficult to determine the exact size that the variable needs to be.

```
const char *filename = "filetoopen.txt";
FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");

if (!f){
    printf("Unable to open file! %s", filename);
    return;
}

char ch;
int counter = 0;
int totalSize,structSize;
int offset = offsetof(struct StructData, data.content);

//length of file
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
totalSize = ftell(f);

//length of struct in file
fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET);
structSize = totalSize - ftell(f) ;

char buffer[structSize];

buffer[0] = '\0';
char *store = buffer;

while (counter <= structSize)
{
    fread(&ch, 1, 1, f);
    store += sprintf(store, "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF));
    counter++;
}
strcat(buffer, store);

printf("%s\n", buffer);

fclose(f);
```

Comment: Why do you need to do `strcat(buffer, store);`? `store` points to `buffer`. Also the man page says `The strings may not overlap`.

Comment: `store` is pointing `buffer`, what's the aim of `strcat`? Also store, at the end of loop, points the null terminator of `buffer`...

Comment: LPs, is the null terminator needed for buffer[0]?

Comment: No, it isn't, as far as the loop is executed, at least, one time.

Comment: BTW your problem is `while (counter <= structSize)`, that should be `while (counter < structSize)`